# How can I determine the real content type of an HTTP response with an incorrect one?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-type

I'm trying to write an extension that corrects 'incorrect' content types. An example situation is a user might click on a link to a PDF file that has the HTTP `Content-Type` set to `application/octet-stream`. In this case, I want to be able to detect that the real content type is `application/pdf`.

A simple but not-so-robust way to do this would be to define my own mappings from file extensions to content types. However, it would be good if I could re-use existing work to do this.

I noticed that Chrome is able to determine how to display files obtained via the `ftp` and `file` protocols, which I don't believe provide content type information. How does Chrome do this? Does it inspect the file contents? Does it check the file extensions? Most importantly, can I programmatically hook into this content type detection functionality for my extension?

Comment: A good place to start would be the unix libmagic system for divining file types from their contents.

Comment: see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: @msw, would I have access to libmagic from a Google Chrome extension? As for magic numbers, that's definitely an option, but it wouldn't work for cases such as a Microsoft Office `.docx` file.

Comment: I meant to cull ideas from libmagic; I have no idea what the Chrome API provides. As far as the docx format: MS didn't give one the means of determining the file type as they did with doc, xls, etc. So if the file system is lying about the extension and there is no way of knowing if you have a docx without cracking it open, so it goes. Google Docs can import a docx; I'm guessing it peeks inside.